# Non greedy regular expression based replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do a non greedy regular expression based replace in javascript for a string like:

```
"blank blank this is blank blank my blank channel for blank blank blank blank audio video transcription blank blank blank blank blank"
```

I am looking for a solution that replace more than ones consecutive occurrence of `blank` with single `blank` globally. For the string above the outcome should be:
`blank this is blank my blank channel for blank audio video transcription blank`

Comment: Why do you think you need a non-greedy regular expression to do that? I mean, what is it about `/blank(\s+blank)*/` that won't work?

Comment: Thanks Pointy, it works like charm.

Comment: Risky. As it stands it replaces a sequence of `blank` and a word starting with `blank`,  like `blanket`.

Comment: @collapsar good point - could add a `\b` to the end of the second "blank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need non-greedy matching. Use

```
/\bblank( blank)+\b/g
```

Comment: Of course, there are no word boundaries in JS :) Use `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This Regex will do the following:

- Find all instances of `blank` followed by either a space or the end of a string
- captures multiple sequential instances

The Regex: `(blank(?:\s+|$))+`

Replace with: `$1`

## Explanation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    blank                    'blank'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (1 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
blank blank this is blank blank my blank channel for blank blank blank blank audio video transcription blank blank blank blank blank
```

**After search and replace**

```
blank this is blank my blank channel for blank audio video transcription blank
```

## Alternatively

If you're looking to replace all instances of multiple spaces with a single space, then I'd just use:

Regex: `\s{2,}`

Replace with: nothing